# How do I build GDAL with OpenCL against a custom CUDA installation?

Tags: c++, makefile, opencl, gdal, osgeo

I am trying to build GDAL against OpenCL to get GPU accelerated raster operations, depending on Cuda. I managed to get `./configure` to complete and start compiling with `make`. However, when compiling `gdalinfo`, the compilation fails because it can't find the OpenCL symbols.

I'm pretty sure it is because a `-lOpenCL` flag is missing somewhere, but (1) I don't know where; and (2) I don't know what to change. So my question is how to correctly configure the build commands to use OpenCL?

The build failure error:

```
echo '#!/bin/sh' > gdal-config
echo 'CONFIG_LIBS="libgdal.la"' >> gdal-config
echo 'CONFIG_DEP_LIBS=" -lcrypto -lpoppler -ljson-c -lfreexl -lqhull -lqhull -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgeos_c -lwebp -lodbc -lodbcinst -lkmlbase -lkmldom -lkmlengine -lkmlxsd -lkmlregionator -lexpat -lxerces-c -lpthread -lopenjp2 -ljasper -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial -lnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lpthread -lsz -lz -ldl -lm -lcurl -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial -lhdf5 -lmfhdfalt -ldfalt -logdi -lgif -ljpeg -lgeotiff -ltiff -lpng -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpq -lzstd -llzma -lz -lpthread -lm -lrt -ldl  -lspatialite -lsqlite3 -lpcre   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcurl        cuda    -lxml2     "' >> gdal-config
echo 'CONFIG_PREFIX="gdal-2.4.2"' >> gdal-config
echo 'CONFIG_CFLAGS="-Iport -Igcore -Ialg -Iogr -Iogr/ogrsf_frmts -Ifrmts/vrt -Iapps"' >> gdal-config
echo 'CONFIG_DATA="data"' >> gdal-config
echo 'CONFIG_VERSION="'`cat ../VERSION`'"' >> gdal-config
echo 'CONFIG_OGR_ENABLED=yes' >> gdal-config  # Deprecated.  Always true.
echo 'CONFIG_GNM_ENABLED=yes' >> gdal-config
echo 'CONFIG_FORMATS=" gxf gtiff hfa aigrid aaigrid ceos ceos2 iso8211 xpm sdts raw dted mem jdem envisat elas fit vrt usgsdem l1b nitf bmp airsar rs2 ilwis rmf leveller sgi srtmhgt idrisi gsg ingr ers jaxapalsar dimap gff cosar pds adrg coasp tsx terragen blx msgn til r northwood saga xyz hf2 kmlsuperoverlay ctg e00grid zmap ngsgeoid iris map cals safe sentinel2 derived prf sigdem ignfheightasciigrid mrf webp wcs wms plmosaic wmts rda eeda grib bsb openjpeg jpeg2000 netcdf hdf5 hdf4 gif jpeg png pcraster  pcidsk rik ozi pdf rasterlite mbtiles postgisraster arg"' >> gdal-config
cat gdal-config.in >> gdal-config
chmod a+x gdal-config
/bin/bash libtool --mode=compile --silent --tag=CXX g++ -std=c++11 -Iport -Igcore -Ialg -Iogr -Iogr/ogrsf_frmts -Ignm -Iapps -DHAVE_AVX_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSSE3_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME -g -O2  -Wall -Wextra -Winit-self -Wunused-parameter -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wlogical-op -Wshadow -Werror=vla -Wdate-time -Wfloat-conversion -Wmissing-declarations -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-operator-names -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant -Wsuggest-override  -Ifrmts/vrt -DGNM_ENABLED -Iport -I/usr/include/openjpeg-2.1 -I/usr/include  -DGDAL_COMPILATION -DHAVE_XERCES -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/xercesc -Iport -I/usr/include/openjpeg-2.1 -I/usr/include  -DGDAL_COMPILATION -I/usr/include/json-c -Iogr/ogrsf_frmts/geojson -Iogr/ogrsf_frmts/generic -Ignm -DHAVE_GEOS=1 -I/usr/include -c -o gdalinfo_bin.lo gdalinfo_bin.cpp
/bin/bash libtool --mode=link --silent g++ -std=c++11  gdalinfo_bin.lo  libgdal.la  -o gdalinfo
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clCreateProgramWithSource'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clReleaseKernel'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clGetSupportedImageFormats'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clCreateImage2D'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clEnqueueMapBuffer'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clGetPlatformIDs'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clGetDeviceInfo'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clCreateBuffer'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clReleaseCommandQueue'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clReleaseContext'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clReleaseEvent'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clGetDeviceIDs'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clReleaseMemObject'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clCreateCommandQueue'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clBuildProgram'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clFinish'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clGetProgramBuildInfo'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clEnqueueReadBuffer'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clReleaseProgram'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clCreateContext'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clSetKernelArg'
.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `clCreateKernel'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
GNUmakefile:82: recipe for target 'gdalinfo' failed
make[1]: *** [gdalinfo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'apps'
GNUmakefile:112: recipe for target 'apps-target' failed
make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
```

I know these symbols are correctly installed, because they are listed if I do for example:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64   # Inform GDAL of Cuda
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH          # Inform GDAL of Cuda
$ cat /usr/local/cuda/include/CL/*  | grep -i clCreateProgramWithSource
clCreateProgramWithSource(cl_context        /* context */,
    ... )
```

I also think GDAL is correctly configured to know about these, because `./configure --with-opencl --with-opencl-include=/usr/local/cuda/include/ --with-opencl-lib=cuda` can find OpenCL.

Therefore, I think it fails because the following command doesn't have `-lOpenCL` added to it, while apparently `gdalinfo` does want it.

```
/bin/bash libtool --mode=link --silent g++ -std=c++11  gdalinfo_bin.lo  libgdal.la  -o gdalinfo
```

So my final question is: How can I modify the build configuration to include -lOpenCL in more places?

Comment: -lOpenCL should be after the libraries using it on the --mode=link line, e.g. after libgdal.la. Not sure how libtool works but maybe add it as libOpenCL.lo.

Comment: Thanks, that already helps! Any idea how I should go about achieving this? I have no more makefile experience than `./configure && make`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to modify any GDAL makefiles to use the OpenCL - the GDAL build script is pretty good in finding everything you need for that. The only option for the `configure` script you need is `--with-opencl=yes` - this `yes` is essential. The options `--with-opencl-include=ARG` and `--with-opencl-lib=ARG` are useful only when your OpenCL installation is not standard - I didn't use them at all and got everything linked correctly.

The CUDA has its own version of OpenCL headers and the loader library, so you can use them even when there are no standard OpenCL (provided by a Linux software updater, for example - the `apt`) on your box. In case of the CUDA was installed in some non-standard location (for example - in your home directory) you have to tell the GDAL `configure` script about that:

```
./configure \
  --with-opencl=yes \
  --with-opencl-include=${HOME}/apps/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include \
  --with-opencl-lib="-L${HOME}/apps/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib -lOpenCL" \
  <other options if needed>
```

Also, you don't need to tell anything to the `configure` script about your CUDA - the OpenCL loader library should find all the necessary CUDA libraries at run time using its internal mechanics.

Comment: Did you link it to CUDA as well? Because I'm having issues with this approach. Running `./configure --with-opencl=yes` leads to `checking for CL/opencl.h... no configure: error: cannot find CL/opencl.h`. How did you install CUDA (run.sh, ubuntu repositories, nvidia repositories, ...)?

Comment: I tried with `./configure --with-opencl=yes --with-opencl-include=/usr/local/cuda/include/ --with-opencl-lib=cuda` and got the same error as in the original post. Without the extra flags, configure still can't find opencl.

Comment: That worked! Gdal compiled successfully against cuda's OpenCL. For me the final command was `./configure --with-opencl=yes --with-opencl-include=/usr/local/cuda/include --with-opencl-lib="-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lOpenCL"`. Now I'm running into other issues (`*** Error in \`gdalwarp': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000012bfce0 ***`) when running the tools, but I guess that's another issue. Thanks!